# how to add a correct check for the presence of a number in brackets in a string?

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I have a list whose elements are in the following format:

```
[(name (string), float 1, float 2), ..]
```

The name field of some of these elements contains a number in parentheses. If it is present, then I need to cut it out of the name string and divide both float variables by it. What is the correct way to do this?

I tried to do this through the search method of the re library, but I don’t understand exactly how the correct action algorithm should look

Comment: Round brackets are not brackets, they're parentheses

Comment: @Reinderien, technically they are only _parentheses_ when denoting a _parenthesis_.

Comment: It's more interesting than that; it's actually [regional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Round_brackets_or_parentheses) though in programming parlance brackets are always square and parens are always round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *[re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.search)* function to confirm the first field contains a numeric value.

I used the following pattern.

```
\(\d+\)$
```

You can then populate a new list, *values_b*, accordingly.

```py
values_a = [('abc (2)', 3, 4), ('def', 5, 6), ('ghi (3)', 7, 8)]
values_b = []
for value in values_a:
    if re.search(r'\(\d+\)$', value[0]):
        a, b, c = value
        x = a[a.find('(') + 1:a.rfind(')')]
        b /= int(x)
        c /= int(x)
        values_b.append((a[:a.rfind(' ')], b, c))
    else:
        values_b.append(value)
```

Output

```
[('abc (2)', 3, 4), ('def', 5, 6), ('ghi (3)', 7, 8)]
[('abc', 1.5, 2.0), ('def', 5, 6), ('ghi', 2.3333333333333335, 2.6666666666666665)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But what if I also need to cut this number and parentheses from the variable name?

Comment: Your logic is too busy. Firstly, you don't have to compile the search pattern on every iteration of the loop. Secondly, if a match is found it will be in `.group(1)` so, there is no reason to do all the `find` calls. Thirdly, you could just convert `x` to an `int` ONCE and use it.

Comment: @Tabalzu, essentially, just create a new list.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy, _"Your logic is too busy ..."_, I have no idea what that means.  _"... you don't have to compile the search pattern on every iteration ..."_, ok.  _"... if a match is found it will be in .group(1) ..."_, there are no capture groups within the regex, take another look.  _"... you could just convert x to an int ONCE and use it."_, I'm not sure what to say, it's such an unnecessary critique.

Comment: @reilas - you're right. My mistake - it would be in `group(0)` just like mine is, except yours will have unnecessary parens in it because you didn't put them in a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

**Use RegEx:**

Assuming your list is something like `("name(5)", 10, 20)`, you can use regex like this:

```
import re

lst = ("name(5)", 10, 20)
pattern = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)")  # Compile a pattern to match digits between parentheses.
nums = pattern.findall(lst[0])  # Find all occurrences of our pattern...
if len(nums):  # And if there are any..
    num = int(nums[0])  # Select the first one.
    print(lst[1] / num, lst[2] / num)  # Do the math.
    # OUTPUT: 2.0 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But what if I also need to cut this number and parentheses from the variable name?

Comment: using `findall` for this is a bit strange since there's only ever one number per name.

Comment: Yeah, `findall` is just the one I know best.